# MongoDb db.Collection.update() deleted my document

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I run an `update` statement on a `mongodb` database and it deleted my document! What did I do wrong?

This is the update statement:

```
db.Question.update( {Name: "IsSomeCompany"}, {ButtonValues: [0, 1, 2] } )
```

I am using `Robomongo` and the reply was `Updated 1 record(s) in 22ms` but when I checked the database the record was gone. What am I missing here?

Comment: What you mean with "record"? Is it supposed be document fields or the whole document? Well, did you know your update query have not any `$set` or `$unset` operator?

Comment: You *Replaced* a document matched with `{Name: "IsSomeCompany"}` criteria with `{ButtonValues: [0, 1, 2] }`. If you're planning to update parts of the matched document, use `$set` operator.

Comment: The tool you use doesn;t matter in this case. I use this syntax for updating multiple documents. db.getCollection('YourDocument').update(
   { "matchingField" : "matchingValue"},
   {$set: { "field": "value" }     
   },
    { multi: true }
)

Comment: @Hamedz thanks. Could you write this is an answer? The documentation for updating is not clear (at least where I looked) and I didn't see that you need the $set. So I think it could be valuable as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use this syntax for updating multiple documents.

```
db.getCollection('YourDocument').update(
   { "matchingField" : "matchingValue"}, 
   { "$set": { "field": "value" } }, 
   { "multi": true } 
)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to update only one field you should use the $set operator.
But if what you want is to replace the document I had the same issue with Mongo and Meteor. I found in Mongo documentation that to replace the document you need not to use a $ operator and only pass field/value pairs:

> The following operation passes an  document that contains only field and value pairs. The  document completely replaces the original document except for the _id field.

```
db.books.update({ item: "XYZ123" },
    {
     item: "XYZ123",
     stock: 10,
     info: { publisher: "2255", pages: 150 },
     tags: [ "baking", "cooking" ]
    })
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-replace-fields

But both in Robomongo and Meteor method this got the document removed.

The only way I found is to use the $set operator and replace every field. BUT this would try to update the mongo '_id', so I think is just a workaround...

```
db.books.update({ item: "XYZ123" },
    {
      $set: {
        item: "XYZ123",
        stock: 10,
        info: { publisher: "2255", pages: 150 },
        tags: [ "baking", "cooking" ]
      }
    })
```

What am I missing here? :/

Comment: For me this answer is a better help than the accepted one. @Ana Turrillo you took the time to explain the usage of `$set` whereas the first one is a small block code with a link to a larger document.